# Read Custom search property using Display Template in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, user-profile-property

Is it possible to read the value of custom crawled property that is mapped to the `refinablestring00` property in a search result web part using Display Templates in SharePoint Online (Office 365)?

How to Create Display Templates that Display custom crawled property in SharePoint Online (Office 365)?

Answer (score 0):

In your display template add the "refinablestring00" to the managed property mapping like below

```
<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">'Title'{Title}:'Title','Department'{Department}:'RefinableString00'</mso:ManagedPropertyMapping>
```

In the code block you can get the value of the property as below,

```
var department = $getItemValue(ctx, "Department").toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start by copying a display template that does most of what you want, like popup hover card, etc. They are stored in the Master Page Gallery under Display Templates. Then add your refinable property and then insert the property reference in the form `ctx.CurrentItem.PropertyName`

The rest is just fighting JavaScript and HTML.

Rename the copy of the file and drag it back into the Gallery. Check it in and test it....a lot!

Then create a Result Type Rule that specifies your criteria and your display template.

http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2013/06/05/introduction-to-sharepoint-2013-display-templates/